# True delay Animation effect in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am working on a custom delay Animation which I started my version 0.0.0 with `asyncAfter` and then updated my code to Version 1.0.0 using `sleep`, I would like to know if there is a native and easy way for such a delay Animation instead my custom way, see the deference in gif or code.

***PS: If you see any bad coding or upgradable code, please let me know.***

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var array: [Int] = [Int]()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 10.0) {
            
            Button("remove all") { array.removeAll() }.foregroundColor(.red)
            
            Button("Way 1") { array += Array(repeating: 0, count: 5) }
            
            Button("Way 2(Custom Code)") {
                
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                    
                    for index in 0...5  {
                        
                        usleep(50_000)
                        
                        DispatchQueue.main.async { array.append(index) }
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            
            ForEach(array.indices, id:\.self) { index in
                
                Image(systemName: "arrowtriangle.up.fill").scaledToFit().frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                
            }
            
        }
        .animation(.default, value: array)
        
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use Combine `Publisher`s to manage the appending/delays. There are multiple ways to accomplish this -- here's one using a `Timer` `Publisher` that is connected with a simple `[Int]` that get zipped together:

```
class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var array: [Int] = [Int]()
    
    private var cancellable : AnyCancellable?
    
    func run() {
        cancellable = Publishers.Zip(Array(0...5).publisher,
                Timer.publish(every: 0.5, on: .main, in: .default).autoconnect()
            )
            .map { $0.0 }
            .sink(receiveValue: { newValue in
                self.array.append(newValue)
            })
    }
    
    func cancel() {
        cancellable?.cancel()
    }
    
    func removeAll() {
        array.removeAll()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {

        VStack(spacing: 10.0) {

            Button("remove all") { viewModel.removeAll() }.foregroundColor(.red)

            Button("Add arrows") {

                viewModel.run()

            }
            
            Button("Cancel") {
                viewModel.cancel()
            }

            ForEach(viewModel.array.indices, id:\.self) { index in

                Image(systemName: "arrowtriangle.up.fill").scaledToFit().frame(width: 25, height: 25)

            }

        }
        .animation(.default, value: viewModel.array)
    }
}
```

This approach lets you avoid `sleep`, but also allows you do other useful things like cancel mid-session.

Comment: I really thank you for your help, but as you can see in your answer you are appending  items to array in more advanced way that I done, which is great! But my question key point was that using a native way instead making a custom way, let me give more explain, I am looking for a code or method that it make us free to appending items to array with a custom code! for example I want just add 10 items all together to array with an action, and I want this native way if it exist could handle it internally like we done it in custom way.

Comment: Your question does not specify that it needs to be "free from appending items to the array". I wouldn't describe anything about my answer as non-native or not internal. I guess I'm a little confused about your requirements and what type of answer you hope it will produce. Are you just looking for something that would add all of the elements at once and then animate the height of the container?

Comment: I would also point out that you specifically said "If you see any bad coding or upgradable code, please let me know." -- this is exactly what I've tried to do.

Comment: I am sorry for any inconvenient, adding items to array one by one in for loop is just making the animation possible,  and it is working in your answer and in my question! NO issue there, so the issue is for me there that I do not need to add items one by one, I just want add like 10 items to my array and get the same effect without bothering me to using a for loop for that. Does it make sense now? PS: You are right about improvement! thanks.

Comment: Seems like it would at least be worth an upvote, then.

Comment: Sorry I was Busy to answer in comments! I really forgot! thanks a lot! 

Comment: At least I have an alternative Answer to accept, if some one does not come with a native way, I am talking about using just animation and it's initialization's, I was hoping for undiscovered initialization of Animation. 

Answer (score 0):

you could try something simple, like this (especially without using `usleep(50_000)`):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var array: [Int] = [Int]()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10.0) {
            Button("remove all") { array.removeAll() }.foregroundColor(.red)
            Button("Way 1") { array += Array(repeating: 0, count: 5) }
            Button("Way 2(Custom Code)") {
                for index in 0...5  {
                    array.append(index)
                }
            }
            ForEach(array.indices, id:\.self) { index in
                Image(systemName: "arrowtriangle.up.fill").scaledToFit().frame(width: 25, height: 25)
            }
        }
        .animation(.linear(duration: 0.5), value: array) // <-- here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but your answer is just the same way that used in `Way 1`, your answer does not create the animation that I am looking for. *PS: About 'sleep', I am not using it happily, but it makes the animation that I want be possible.*